# Compaq Smart Array 431 with 3.13 kernel

Tags: linux, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, hp

is there any way to use Compaq Smart Array 431 controller on 3.x kernel?

I have 431 board with 4 disks, that are seen by the controller during POST, but I'm unable to communicate with it on Linux Mint 17 x86_64 with 3.13.0-24 kernel.
I had it working on other machine with 2.6 kernel.

Tried loading `cciss` and `hpsa` and reloading udev, but nothing happened.
Also tried to recompile kernel with `CONFIG_BLK_CPQ_CISS_DA=y`.

The device is
`04:00.0 RAID bus controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21554 (rev 01)`
and according to Debian HCL should be driven by `cpqarray` driver, that I believe is controlled via config flag mentioned above.

I have `cpqarrayd` installed, but it won't start since it cannot detect the controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That equipment is just too old to use safely...

[image]

The [Smart Array 431](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04285093) RAID controller is [pre-HPSA and pre-CCISS](http://cciss.sourceforge.net), dating back to the old [CPQARRAY](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/cpqarray.txt) driver. So you're trying to use ancient 1999-era hardware with a 2014 operating system. I don't think that's reasonable.

The cpqarray driver was removed from the Linux kernel config options in version 3.13 - [Here's the Git commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7badfb1c34f85e2b68252e4596d96e9b76f2b0ac) and accompanying notes:

> block: disable cpqarray in Kconfig Mike writes:
>
> "cpqarray hasn't been used in over 12 years. It's doubtful that anyone
>   still uses the board. It's time the driver was removed from the
>   mainline  kernel.  The only updates these days are minor and mostly
>   done by people  outside of HP."
>
> If nobody yells, we'll remove it from the kernel tree completely for
>   3.15.

You *could* yell, but in reality, that board and anything attached to it should be retired. 4.3GB Wide SCSI hard disks, for instance :)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that is a really old piece of hardware, but all SCSI RAID controllers I have, are taken out of prehistoric HP servers, so I'm trying to do something with these. Anyway, thanks for the answer, at least I know which commit I need to revert in my sources.

Comment: It's not only old, but I can't think of any reason you'd want to use one today. Is this for experimentation?

Comment: Well, I need some failsafe storage (not much), so I thought of these boards lying somewhere around, instead of buying new controllers and disks.

Comment: @daneos The only _good_ reason to use one of these is to rescue data you can't get to any other way. If you need a cheap RAID controller, see eBay; reasonably modern used RAID cards can be had for $50-$100. Not to mention that there are now _USB sticks_ that have more storage than the drives which will connect to that ancient controller.

Comment: 4.3 Gigabytes disks FTW!!

Comment: @ewwhite I had a couple of **full height** 9GB SCSI drives around that time. I was glad to get rid of those... in 2001!

Comment: I have 18GB disks connected to it :) I have tried setting up software RAID on 2 16GB USB sticks, but it was tragically slow. Nevertheless, now my ancient controller works, and I'm going to use it anyway.